# WordPress error when update to new version

Tags: errors

Got this error when I update my WordPress site, and now my site completely blank with this words.

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class WP_REST_Blocks_Controller in /home/u323482793/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg/lib/class-wp-rest-blocks-controller.php on line 0**

please help and show me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The Gutenberg editor is from Wordpress 5.0 part of the core code. After the Wordpress update, you have two `WP_REST_Blocks_Controller` class definitions, one in WP core code, second in plugin.

Disable Gutenberg plugin by changing the name of the directory or removing it.